# App not working on certain phones

Tags: java, android, button

People have been experiemcing a problem with my android app. Apperently what is happening is on phones such as the Droid x and cliq cupcake have been experiencing the main menu not showing the letters on the buttons and in some occasions it will cause a force close in certain sections. My buttons do have picture backgrounds if that could be the cause and the app is set for version 1.6. Not sure if either has anything to do with it. If anyone has experienced it or has any ideas I would appreciate some help. Thanks alot

Comment: If you would like to check it out if you have one of those phones or get an idea feel free to take a look. Its The Stoner's Handbook

Comment: Have seem this with certain phones in our app as well - mainly Evo.

Answer (score 0):

It should work on every phone if you read this post carefully

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In best practices part recommended list is here.

- Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or the dp unit (instead of px), when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file
- Do not use AbsoluteLayout
- Do not use hard coded pixel values in your code
- Use density and/or resolution specific resources

Every android developer should read that post to support for multiple screens.

Hope this helps